# Trying IPv6 through Miredo, IPv6-only hostnames not working as I would like

Tags: networking, dns, ipv6

I was fooling around with IPv6 and Miredo as my ISP is IPv4 only.

I have Miredo working and can do things like

```
ping6 ipv6.google.com
```

or open Firefox to URL http://[2a00:1450:4003:808::200e]

But now I wanted to use Firefox to open http://ipv6.google.com and I receive a "Server Not Found" error. I have already checked the flag `network.dns.disableIPv6` in the `about:config` settings and has no effect.

I have been reading other pitfalls but I am missing something as none of the solutions I found change anything on my scenario.

The following work:

```
host ipv6.google.com
dig aaaa ipv6.google.com
dig -6 aaaa ipv6.google.com  # I added a ipv6 DNS just in case
wget -6 ipv6.google.com
```

The following don't work:

```
ping ipv6.google.com
dig ipv6.google.com  # doesn't yield the IPv6 address only the cname
dig ipv6.l.google.com  # doesn't yield any address
wget ipv6.google.com
```

I also tried to play around the file `/etc/gai.conf`, but failed to achieve anything.

Chrome and Chromium are failing in the same fashion as Firefox, so I assume that the problem is system-wide, not application specific. Not sure how or why.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Teredo/Miredo are not recommended ways to get IPv6. They rely on 3rd party (often badly maintained) relays, just like 6to4, which has been deprecated. Don't expect it to work flawlessly.

About the commands that are failing. The `ping` command is only for IPv4 on most platforms. To ping over IPv6 you'll need to use `ping6` like the example you started with.

That the `dig` command by default asks for `A` records (IPv4), so not getting an answer when asking for the IPv4 records of an IPv6-only hostname is expected. Your examples where you explicitly request `AAAA` records are the correct ones.

Why `wget` doesn't work I don't know. Might well be some Teredo/Miredo issue.

Comment: care to recommend an alternative to Teredo/Miredo for a "movable" laptop? I was planning to use Tunnelbroker for my home network, and it was nice to avoid a full VPN only to get IPv6 on-the-go

Comment: Tunnels are hard for movable devices. I think a VPN (which is essentially an encrypted tunnel) is the best option.